# Custom widget as Flutter mobile app keyboard

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I am making a calculator app, and when I click on an input field, I want to show a custom keyboard (basically a custom made widget that is the whole keyboard), but have no clue how to make it look like it is a real keyboard - opens from the bottom like a real one, looks like the real one, similarly functions like a normal one.

**How do I make a widget appear and act as a keyboard in flutter?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  onTap: () {
    // Your tap handling code here
  },
  child: YourChildWidget(),
)"

AbsorbPointer(
  absorbing: true, // Set to true to block gestures
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      // Your tap handling code here (will not trigger if absorbing is true)
    },
    child: YourChildWidget(),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Flutter,** you can create a widget that mimics the behavior of a keyboard using a combination of Flutter's built-in widgets and user input handling. To create a custom widget that behaves like a keyboard, you'll typically use GestureDetector to capture user input and modify the state of your widget accordingly.

**The steps to create a simple custom keyboard widget in Flutter**

- Create a Custom Keyboard Widget Class: Define a custom widget class
  that represents your keyboard. This class will extend StatefulWidget.
  The state of the widget will hold the current keyboard input.

  Design Your Keyboard UI:  Within the build method of your widget,
  design the UI of your keyboard using Flutter widgets like Container,
  Row, Column, and FlatButton. Each button on the keyboard can be a
  FlatButton or a GestureDetector that responds to user input.

  Handle User Input: Wrap each button or key with a GestureDetector to
  capture taps or gestures. In the gesture handler, update the keyboard
  input state (e.g., append characters to the input string).

  Display the Keyboard: Add your custom keyboard widget to the Flutter
  UI where you want the keyboard to appear. Typically, this is within a
  Stack or a Positioned widget to overlay it on top of your input
  fields.

  Interact with Input Fields: For input fields that should use your
  custom keyboard, you can set up controllers or handlers to insert
  text from the custom keyboard into those fields when keys are
  pressed.

examples

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomKeyboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomKeyboardState createState() => _CustomKeyboardState();
}

class _CustomKeyboardState extends State<CustomKeyboard> {
  String inputText = '';

  void _handleKeyTap(String key) {
    setState(() {
      inputText += key;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        // Input field where you want to display the text
        TextField(
          controller: TextEditingController(text: inputText),
        ),
        // Custom keyboard UI
        Row(
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => _handleKeyTap('1'),
              child: Container(
                // Customize your key appearance here
                child: Text('1'),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => _handleKeyTap('2'),
              child: Container(
                // Customize your key appearance here
                child: Text('2'),
              ),
            ),
            // Add more keys as needed
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Custom Keyboard Example'),
        ),
        body: CustomKeyboard(),
      ),
    ));
```

Comment: I think I can achieve all things but the positioning. I am trying to do it with `ShowBottomSheet` and `ShowModalBottomSheet`, but when I tap outside them, it just closes the keyboard. I want it not to act as a barrier, meaning when I tap on something outside, it should work (maybe I tap on some other button on my screen, not on the keyboard widget) as well as close it, but I can't seem to do that.

Comment: where tapping outside the keyboard widget should both work with other widgets on the screen and close the keyboard, you can use a combination of Stack, Positioned, and GestureDetector. The idea is to create a custom keyboard that's placed above your content but doesn't act as a modal barrier when tapped outside. if you need any example

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. But when I use `GestureDetector`, it acts as a modal barrier, since it interrups the tap. How can I avoid that?

Comment: you can try a few different approaches depending on your specific use case:

1. **Use the `behavior` property**: You can modify the `behavior` property of the `GestureDetector` to control how it interacts with other gestures. The `GestureDetector` widget has a `behavior` property that you can set to various constants, such as `HitTestBehavior.translucent`, `HitTestBehavior.opaque`, or `HitTestBehavior.deferToChild`.

Comment: 2. **Use `AbsorbPointer`**: If you want to completely ignore gestures on the `GestureDetector` and its child, you can wrap it in an `AbsorbPointer` widget. This widget will prevent any interaction with its subtree. This can be useful if you want to temporarily disable the `GestureDetector`.

Comment: Oh, the `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent` is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

number_key: ^0.0.4 use this package from pub.dev it is a virtual number key

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).